# I've answered my own bounty question, and days later someone provided a duplicate answer, and the bounty goes to him?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I offered a bounty on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459803/save-stack-trace-tsk-and-struct-stack-trace-is-no-longer-available-in-linux-5-2) that I asked last year.

I have provided the answer with working code, and days later someone else provided a "duplicate" answer without code.

Currently the highest voted "duplicated" answer is borrowed from existing comments and answers, and more importantly does not even contain a code example.

Because the bounty can't go back to the poster, now the bounty goes to him.

I feel this is not fair.

Comment: This is intentional and how the system works. See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: If you don't like the answer, downvote it. Add comment explaining why, so others can decide to downvote as well. In case of actual plagiarism, flag and ask for deletion. That's about all your options.

Comment: This can be handled by the community. A moderator, if needs must. It does not warrant a rule change.

Comment: "Please either cancel the bounty or assign the bounty to my answer." You can't win your own bounty, that would make the whole thing pointless. The other answerer seems very reasonable, I don't know what your issue is with them, they even left a comments saying they did not see your answer and added a bit of explanation to their answer to differentiate it.

Comment: @MarkKirby because I've resolved the problem first and the later answer does not have any working code. Sometimes the most voted answer is not the best one.

Comment: "Sometimes the most voted answer is not the best one." absolutely, that is true but you know how these sites work, votes are everything for better or worse. If I was you I would just lean in to it and ask the other answerer to expand their answer with an example and then if it still wins the bounty, at least it is a good answer to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the time of me answering this question, the "duplicate" answer you are talking about has a score of 1, and if it doesn't reach a score of at least 2 at the end of the grace period, the answer will not receive the bounty (see [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/771581)).

However, the answer can't be called a duplicate because it is not a copy-paste of an already existing answer. Even though it may have borrowed ideas from your answer, it has details not present in your answer and is a new answer in all rights.

But, if you ever step upon an answer which you think is a duplicate, flag it as **in need of moderator intervention** explaining your reason, and it would be removed if it is genuinely a duplicate. Also, the community is at work at all times, and if such answers are present, then they would be downvoted a lot. So, I don't think that a change of rule is required.